# Computing a non-square correlation matrix (one x-var vs multiple y-vars) + deriving regression-line-scatterplot and correlation-plus-p-value-plot

Tags: r, matrix, plot, correlation, scatter-plot

I am quite new to R have to proceed about 300 dataframes with 11 variables, each df with about 40 to 100 observations.
I am only interested in the correlations (pearson) between only **one** of these variables against the other 10 variables (not all against all).

From these 10 pairs (per dataframe) I now would like to get:

1. A 1x10-non-square-correlation-'matrix' including corr-value, p-value (,
   confidence). For time saving reasons the function should **really calculate only these 10 correlations** (, not calculating a whole square matrix and then supressing the non-needed part with the output). This for example seems to be possible with the `rstatix::cor_test`
2. A 1x10 gridded/facetted scatterplot with regression line (ideally showing the corr-values)
3. A 1x10 gridded/facetted corrplot with corr- and ideally p-value.
   Below you'll find some illustration of my 'wishes'

I tried around with `ggcorrplot` `GGally` `rstatix` `corrr` and maybe others. In result my issue-'complex' is now, that

- a lot of packages/functions don't provide non-square matrices,
- the functions which do support non-sqare (as e.g. `rstatics::cor_test`) seem to be not provided by according plot functions or just by very basic plot functions, - or my expertise might be to weak for suiting plot functions.
- the results of the full-matrix-functions might be reduced to 1x10 after calculating. But this needs 10 times of calculating time. And secondly, especcially the suiting of the plot functions (together with ggplot2) seems to be often quite tricky then.
- I could use 1x1 instead. But this would result in a huge amount of single calculations, also not practical to plot, I guess.
- I am not sure at the moment whether my issue-list is complete now. However, though there are quite nice functions for each single step, I do not bring them together.

So my question is:
Does anybody have an approach for me that melts the single steps to a consistent overall process, - maybe with giving a code example based on `mtcars`? 
For plotting I would prefer ggplot2 or ggplot2-based packages.

---

Finally my illustration (based on `mtcars`)

Referring to point 1:
This is an example how I would imagine 1x10-'matrix', done in this case with the `rstatics::cor_test`. But I don't know / could not figure out whether there is an option to translate it into plots according to point 2 and 3.

```
> mtcars %>% cor_test(mpg)
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   var1  var2    cor statistic        p conf.low conf.high method 
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1 mpg   cyl   -0.85     -8.92 6.11e-10  -0.926     -0.716 Pearson
 2 mpg   disp  -0.85     -8.75 9.38e-10  -0.923     -0.708 Pearson
 3 mpg   hp    -0.78     -6.74 1.79e- 7  -0.885     -0.586 Pearson
 4 mpg   drat   0.68      5.10 1.78e- 5   0.436      0.832 Pearson
 5 mpg   wt    -0.87     -9.56 1.29e-10  -0.934     -0.744 Pearson
 6 mpg   qsec   0.42      2.53 1.71e- 2   0.0820     0.670 Pearson
 7 mpg   vs     0.66      4.86 3.42e- 5   0.410      0.822 Pearson
 8 mpg   am     0.6       4.11 2.85e- 4   0.318      0.784 Pearson
 9 mpg   gear   0.48      3.00 5.4 e- 3   0.158      0.710 Pearson
10 mpg   carb  -0.55     -3.62 1.08e- 3  -0.755     -0.250 Pearson
```

Referring to point 2:
This would be for me a nice presentation of scatterplots with regr.-line: only one row with the variable of interest against all others (in this example just 1x5), ideally with corrvalue and stars. 
 Image is derived by photoshopping a `ggpair`-result by cutting the triangle to one line and labelling the scatter panels with the p-value. --> But no idea how to suite to 'non-square' with R.

[image]

Referring to point 3:
This is how I would basically imagine the corr-plot: only one row according to the previous example, here just with corr-value, but ideally also with p-value. 
Image is derived by photoshopping a `ggcorrplot`-result by cutting the triangle to one line. --> But no idea how to suite with R.

[image]

Comment: All the best with this one, I have the same problem.